# Get finger x-axis position using jquery /js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, cocoa-touch

I would like to get the finger position of the x-axis on ipad . I will capture 2 time, compare the difference and find out whether the user is scrolling right or left. However, my code can only capture the first x-position but not the second one, how to fix that problem? Thanks

```
$('#all_pages').bind('scrollstart', function(event) {
var e = event.originalEvent;
var beforeX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX;
var afterX = 0;
setTimeout(function(){afterX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX},200);
alert(beforeX + ',' + afterX);
});
```